# Basic ajax logic

Tags: php, html, ajax

Upon suggestion of using Ajax for an html page, I decided to attempt to learn how it works.  In my example, I'm just trying to get the response from a php file (which just echoes a simple string as a test) but it doesn't work, in that nothing actually happens.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html>
<head>
   <title> Incident Center </title>
   <!--<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://web.njit.edu/~swp5/assignment/style/style.css">-->
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
   <script type="text/javascript">
    function onsubmit()
    {
        var sender;
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            sender=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            sender=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        sender.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (sender.readyState==4 && sender.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=sender.responseText;
            }
        }
        sender.open("GET","proz.php",true);
        sender.send();
    }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="header">
        Incident Center 
    </div>

            <p>
                <button onclick="onsubmit()">Test</button>
            </p>


    <div id="myDiv"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: For one: your HTML is malformed. Missing a `<form>` opening tag. Don't know if this is causing the problem though.

Comment: Sorry, I altered the code a bit from its original state just to simplify it so I could narrow down the possibilities.  I just forgot to delete the other tag.

Comment: Have you checked the response code after your request? The responseText is only set if sender.status == 200.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Opera 11.51 here, it doesn't actually like the fact that you use `onsubmit()` as a function name. Presumably because `onsubmit()` is actually already an eventhandler hook of a `<button>` element itself. I presume other browsers won't like this function name either.

So, first off, rename the function. Let's assume `dosubmit()` here.

Furthermore, you should wrap a button in a `<form>` element. And because a default button, acts as a submit button, the form is being submitted, causing the page to reload.

To prevent this, you should let the function `return false;` and call the function like so `onclick="return dosubmit()"`, if you are going to call it inline like this, or make the button a button of type `button`, like so: `<button type="button" onclick="dosubmit()">`

Answer (score 1):

As I already mentioned in my comment, you should check the response code of your request to see if something went wrong. Add the following line to the start of your `onreadystatechanged` function:

```
alert(sender.readyState + ', ' + sender.status + ', ' + sender.responseText);
```

Based on this output you can probably determine your error.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you use jQuery ? http://www.jquery.com/

Comment: In his question he states he is trying to learn how it all works. In that scenario it is probably better to try it like this, instead of using jQuery that does all the actual AJAX work behind the scenes.

Answer (score 0):

Send doesn't actually display anything.  Send calls the page and populates two different variables. What send does is populates the "responseXML" and "responseText" properties of the sender.  Try after your send:

```
alert(sender.responseText);
```

See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest

Answer (score 0):

It's much easier to use jQuery to do this as it has a built in AJAX function. Your code would look like this:

```
jQuery.ajax({
    type: 'get',
    url: 'proz.php',
        error: function(r) {
            alert("Something went wrong - "+r);
        }
    success: function(response) {
        alert(response);
    }
});
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Same comment as with Davids answer: In his question he states he is trying to learn how it all works. In that scenario it is probably better to try it like this, instead of using jQuery that does all the actual AJAX work behind the scenes.